# How to find coefficients $a$ and $b$ when given the curl?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So we have a vectorfield $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ with curl

$$
\nabla  \times f = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\cfrac{{\partial f_a }}{{\partial x_b }} - \cfrac{{\partial f_b }}{{\partial x_a }}}  \\
   {\cfrac{{\partial f_d }}{{\partial x_e }} - \cfrac{{\partial f_e }}{{\partial x_d }}}  \\
   {\cfrac{{\partial f_g }}{{\partial x_h }} - \cfrac{{\partial f_h }}{{\partial x_g }}}  \\
\end{array}} \right).
$$

Give the right value for the first parameteres $a$ and $b$.

How do I find these values? I'm also confussed by the letters $a$, $b$, $d$, $e$, $h$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the parameters are supposed to be dimension indices, and that you're supposed to replace them with either $1$, $2$, or $3$ (or whatever notation you use to denote distinct dimensions in 3-D). $f_a$ should be the $a$-component of the vector field in question, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_b}$ should be the partial derivative in the $b$th direction.

The answer should follow directly from the definition of the curl.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions, but what are dimension indices?

Comment: Not a problem! Normally when you’re dealing with a Cartesian coordinate system in 3-D, you use $x$, $y$, and $z$ to label the different dimensions; in general, some authors (like the one who came up with that exercise) like to use $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ instead. Dimension indices are just a way to keep track of which is which, in a way that can extend to arbitrarily many dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the help :)
But if the vector field is in three dimensions, why do we have 6 parameters and not 3?

Comment: I think whoever made the exercise chose to do that to not give away that there are only three possible choices for the indices in 3-D. So even though you have six different things you’re looking for, they can only have one of three values ($1$, $2$, or $3$).

Comment: Ohh, I see! Now I understand. Thank you so much for all the help :)